# Right versus left derivative by increasing one-sided derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

Condider a map $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$, $D$ open interval.
Let be $y,z\in D$, $y<z$. Suppose that $f$ has everywhere in $D$ both left and right derivative (this implies that $f$ is continuous), both *increasing*.
I want to show that
$$
f'(y^+)\le f'(z^-).
$$

I have found a way, but I'm not completely convinced that it is formally correct:
$$
f'(y^+)
=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{f(y+\varepsilon)-f(y)}{\varepsilon}
\overset{\forall\delta}{\le} 
  f'((z-\delta)^+)
= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{f(z-\delta+\varepsilon)-f(z-\delta)}{\varepsilon}
\overset{\varepsilon=\delta}{=} \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{f(z)-f(z-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}
=f'(z^-)
$$
where $\delta>0$ and $y<z-\delta$.

> Is there a way to formalise my proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'll use the notation $f'_+$ and $f'_-$ for the right and left derivative.)

Unfortunately your proof does not work. This
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{f(z-\delta+\varepsilon)-f(z-\delta)}{\varepsilon}
\overset{\varepsilon=\delta}{=} \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{f(z)-f(z-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}
$$
makes no sense because $\delta$ is fixed and the limits are taken for $\varepsilon \to 0 $. Also it would imply that $f'_+(z-\delta) = f'_-(z)$ for $0 < \delta < z-y$, which is true only if $f$ is linear between $y$ and $z$.

---

What we can show is that
$$ \tag{*}
 f'_+(y) \le \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y} \le f'_-(z)
$$
for $y < z$, which implies the desired conclusion. (This is motivated by the fact that both an increasing right derivative and an increasing left derivative imply that $f$ is *convex.*)

The proof of $(*)$ mimics the proof of Rolle's theorem and the mean-value theorem. We consider the function
$$
 g(x) = f(x) - (x-y)\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}
$$
which is continuous and satisfies $g(y) = g(z)$. It follows that $g$ attains its maximum on the interval $[y, z]$ at some point $w \in [y, z)$. Then $g'_+(w) \le 0$ and it follows that
$$
f'_+(y) \le f'_+(w) = g'_+(w) + \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y} \le \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y} \, .
$$
This proves the left inequality in $(*)$, the proof of the right inequality works similarly.

Comment: Nice proof.  My thought was to prove directly using the definition of the directional derivative that the limit as $y'$ approaches $y$ from the right hand side of the left derivatives of the $y'$ converge to the right derivative at $y$. Then, the left derivative at $z$ has to be larger than that. But, I didn't work out the details.

Comment: The question comes from Artin, 1964, The Gamma function, page  4. In the final step of Th.1.3 he use 1.6, that in mho cannot be used, because convexity is what we want to prove and 1.6 is derived using convexity.

Comment: @Wyatt: I do not have that book, so I cannot comment on that. My approach was “inspired” by convexity, but does not use it.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/THEGAMMAFUNCTION/page/n5/mode/1up

Comment: @MartinR I think we should be able to prove the seemingly stronger statement that 
$\lim_{z\to y^+}f'_-(z)=f'_+(y)$.  Your proof includes a statement that $f$ is convex. Hence, the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765513/can-we-recover-left-hand-derivative-from-right-hand-derivative?rq=1) states $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and this equality is true (the proof is for the other side, but I think it also applies for either side).

Comment: @MartinR For the function $g(x)$ you defined. Is it true that $g'_+(y) \le 0$?

Comment: @JohnL: I used that $g'_+(w) \le 0$, and that is because $g$ has a maximum at $w$.

Comment: @MartinR I understand. But, I was wondering if the right hand derivative at $y$ must be less than or equal to 0.

Comment: @JohnL: $g'_+$ and $f'_+$ differ by a constant, so that $g'_+$ is increasing as well. Therefore $g'_+(y) \le g'_+(w) \le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove the stronger statement  $$\lim_{x\to y^+}f'_-(x)=f'_+(y)$$

By the Monotone Convergence Theorem $\lim_{x\to y^+}f'_-(x)$ exists. Call that limit $A$.

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given and choose a value of $\delta>0$ such that both of these are true:
$$x\in(y,y+\delta] \implies f'_-(x)\in \left[A,A+\frac{\epsilon}2 \right]$$
and
$$\left|\frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta}-f'_+(y)\right|\le \frac{\epsilon}2$$
That is possible because of the definitions of the left hand derivative and the limit.

Similar to the answer from @MartinR, define the function $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta}(x-y)$ so that $g(y)=g(y+\delta)$ and both $g'_-(x)=f'_-(x)-\frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta}$ and $g'_+(x)=f'_+(x)-\frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta}$ are increasing.

Claim 1. $g'_+(y) \le 0$
This follows because if it were not true, then $g'_+(x)$ would have to be positive for all $x\in  (y,y+\delta)$. That would imply $g$ is increasing ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485828/f-0-1-rightarrow-mathbbr-countinous-with-non-negative-right-hand-deriv)) in that interval and it would be impossible for $g(y+\delta)$ to equal $g(y)$.

Claim 2. $g'_-(y+\delta) \ge 0$
Same argument as Claim 1. If it were not true, then $g'_-$ would have to be negative in the whole interval which would make it impossible for the function to have the same value at both ends of the interval.

Now,
$$g'_-(y+\delta)\ge0$$
$$f'_-(y+\delta)-\frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta}\ge0$$
$$f'_-(y+\delta) \ge \frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta} \ge f'_+(y)-\frac{\epsilon}2$$
We also know that $f'_-(y+\delta)\in \left[A,A+\frac{\epsilon}2 \right]$

Thus,
$$A \ge f'_-(y+\delta)-\frac{\epsilon}2 \ge f'_+(y)-\epsilon \label{eq1}\tag{1}$$

On the other hand,
$$g'_-(y)\le0$$
$$f'_-(y)-\frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta}\le0$$
$$f'_-(y) \le \frac{f(y+\delta)-f(y)}{\delta} \le f'_+(y)+\frac{\epsilon}2$$

So,
$$A \le f'_-(y+\delta) \le f'_+(y)+\frac{\epsilon}2 \label{eq2}\tag{2}$$

Combining the two inequalities (1) and (2), since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $A=f'_+(y)$.

To answer the original question, if $z>y$ then by the monotonicity assumption $f'_-(z)>\lim_{x\to y^+}f'_-(x)=f'_+(y)$

Comment: Note that $\delta$ is restricted by the condition $0 < \delta< z-y$. I think that *that* part is actually correct, the error lies in the next step.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how the equation $f'_+(y)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}f'_-(y+\varepsilon)$ is obtained?

Comment: The mean value theorem requires that $f$ is *differentiable* (and then the claim becomes trivial). I am note sure what $A$ in (ii) is but it seems to depend on $z$, but you treat it as a constant later.

Comment: @MartinR Is this OK now?